# Django No reverse error when user uses email as Username

Tags: python, django

When a User uses an email as the Username the reverse for view fails. But when I change the username to a non-email username using admin panel, it works great. I have searched a lot but couldn't find similar issue.

My User Model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):    
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)    
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

View responsible:

```
class UserUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = "accounts/user_update.html"
    form_class = UserChangingForm
    model = CustomUser
    slug_field = 'username'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'username'
    success_message = '%(username)s was updated successfully'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('accounts:user_update', kwargs={'username': self.object.username})
```

Urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as authViews

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = {
    path('signup/', views.UserSignupView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', authViews.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('<slug:username>/profile/', views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_update'),}
```

The error in template is thrown by:

Error message:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'user_update' with arguments '('kkdsjfsdifisdfj@gmail.com',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) > tried: ['accounts/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/profile/$']

I am thinking of preventing users from using special character in Username field while signup. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `@` is not a valid character for a `slug` url parameter. It's also not valid to put in the path anyway

Comment: Your regex expression (**`[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+`**) is not catching the input string `kkdsjfsdifisdfj@gmail.com`. To get it to work, change your regex expression to **`[-a-zA-Z0-9_@.]+`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is in this line

```
path('<slug:username>/profile/', views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_update'),
```

here your username name is an email. but you defined it as a slug field. change `slug` field.

**update it with**

`path('<username>/profile/', views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_update'),`

> if you want to prevent the special character in Username field then you can use a regex and you'll need to use `re_path()` or `url()`

```
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(r'(?P<username>\w+|[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/profile/$', views.UserUpdateView.as_view(), name='user_update'),
```

> please use proper regex here. for email you cab check this. 
>   [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: Thanks, removing slug from url path solved the problem. Can I use UnicodeUsernameValidator and regex with username_validator field in my Abstract model class to prevent special character?

Comment: if you want to use custom regex, then you need to use `re_path` instead of `path`